# jQuery not removing elements from outlook.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, outlook

I am creating a Chrome extension with jQuery which removes advertisements from outlook.com, however when I put the ID or Class it doesn't remove it.

I have tried this.

```
$("#RadAd_Skyscraper").css( "display", "none" );
$("#SkyscraperContent").css( "display", "none" );
$("#RightRailContainer").remove();
```

Comment: check if those elements exist when your code runs

Comment: I have done an Inspect Element on those elements.

Comment: that doesn't mean they exist when your code runs and aren't inserted dynamically afterwards

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. Should I do this?
$( document ).ready(function() {
});

Comment: well that part is a given that should be used with jQuery. Also make sure you include jQuery if it doesn't already exist

Comment: Ok. So what should I do to check if those elements exist?

Comment: check length....that part is an easy google search

Comment: Please read through and confirm you understood the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). I have a feeling you may be executing this code in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the elements are within an iframe. You'll have to get a reference to the iframe, then get the DOM element within it and then do the hide/remove on it.

For example:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-id');
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('RadAd_Skyscraper').style.display = 'none';
```